# Read XML file from URL, comes up empty

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

I am trying to read a XML file from a URL.
The URL and file are fine, they hold currency rates.

When running the code 9 out of 10 times, no content comes back.

Here is the code:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml");
        int currID = 0;
        Dictionary<int, Currency> curr; // declares the dictionary  
        curr = new Dictionary<int, Currency>();

        var data = from item in doc.Descendants("CURRENCY") // LINQ the informartion from the xml to data variable
                   select new
                   {
                       name = item.Element("NAME").Value,
                       country = item.Element("COUNTRY").Value,
                       currencyCode = item.Element("CURRENCYCODE").Value,
                       rate = Convert.ToDouble(item.Element("RATE").Value),
                       unit = Convert.ToDouble(item.Element("UNIT").Value),
                       change = Convert.ToDouble(item.Element("CHANGE").Value),
                   };

        foreach (var xn in data) // run in foreach on the data that we read from the xml and put it in a currency variable into the dictionary
        {
            Currency currency = new Currency();

            currency.Name = xn.name;
            currency.Country = xn.country;
            currency.CurrencyCode = xn.currencyCode;
            currency.Rate = Convert.ToDouble(xn.rate);
            currency.Unit = Convert.ToDouble(xn.unit);
            currency.Change = Convert.ToDouble(xn.change);

            curr.Add(currID, currency);
            currID++;
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Currency> entry in curr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Value.CurrencyCode);
        }
```

I have edited the code to see the output, I get nothing.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're doing conversions in your `foreach` that you don't need.  You really don't need the `foreach` or anonymous type at all.  I get data 10/10 times i hit the service, I have no idea why you wouldn't

Comment: Ditto...   I'm running it and just printing out the name and country... works every time.  Is there an exception or perhaps you have other code that makes it seem like this code isn't running?  Also as @Jonesy says... no need to convert twice.

Comment: hmm.. what is the point of the data variable? doc.Elements are comprised of XElements.. so it should just be foreach (XElement elm in doc)

Comment: I didn't remove the XMLReader tag reference.. but I don't see it being used in this code.. The Reader objects usually use streams.. There is certainly a stream occurring in the Load() method.. but it's not in the scope of your usage here..

Comment: @BrettCaswell, I have edited my code just a bit and I still get nothing.
Opened a new project and still nothing.

Can it be something with cookies of some sort ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@David Faiz It Works!

```
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
    xDoc.Load(@"http://www.boi.org.il//currency.xml"); 
    XmlNodeList xmllist = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("CURRENCIES"); 
    Console.WriteLine(xmllist.Count);
```

You have must add // slashes in the **URL**. That is why u got the 'xmllist.Count' as Zero.

Comment: @jai
Hey, I have ran the code and it returned the xml properly, but every other time. I once again, get nothing.

Any idea why?

Comment: @jai, you're escaping twice here eh? with `@` and `//currency.xml`.. thats a typo right?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick refactor of your code..

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml");

foreach (XElement elm in doc.Elements) 
{
    Currency currency = new Currency();

    currency.Name = elm.Element("NAME").Value;
    currency.Country = elm.Element("COUNTRY").Value;
    currency.CurrencyCode = elm.Element("CURRENCYCODE").Value;
    currency.Rate = Convert.ToDouble(elm.Element("RATE").Value);
    currency.Unit = Convert.ToDouble(elm.Element("UNIT").Value);
    currency.Change = Convert.ToDouble(elm.Element("CHANGE").Value);

    MessageBox.Show(elm.Element("CURRENCYCODE").Value);

    curr.Add(currID, currency);
    currID++;
}
```

However, I'm not sure this addresses the underlying issue you're having..

You could include the System.Net namespace and initialize a XMLHttpRequest object and use the Response stream with the static XDocument.Load() method..

Comment: The reason I suggest using the XMLHttpRequest object and than using the response stream is because you could better account for the site's response statuses, contentType and such.. If you need me to expand on that with a code sample.. let me know

Comment: I am super new to C#, can you please help with the proper use of a XMLHTTPRequest object?
I have found several examples but not sure which one of them fits my needs.

Comment: I have tried this code as well:

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load("http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml");

            XmlNodeList xmllist =      xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("CURRENCY");

            Console.WriteLine(xmllist.Count);


I get back that 'xmllist.Count' is zero.

Can it be something with my computer?